# Proof that supremum doesn' exist

Tags: continuity, supremum-and-infimum

We know that if $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then the function is bounded.

$c \in [a,b]$

$c = \sup\{z \in (a,b]:  f\text{ is bounded on }[a,z)\}$

If function is continuous on interval $[a,+\infty)$ how can we prove that supremum doesn't exist.

Comment: I think you must be careful with your quantifier. First, by Weierstrass Theorem 1, **every** (all) continuous funcion on a compact subset of $\;\Bbb R\;$ is bounded there. The last part should be :*not every* continuous funcions on $\;[a,\infty)\;$ is bounded there"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prove it, since it may exist. If, say, $f$ is constant, that supremum does exist.

But it doesn't *always* exist. Take $f\colon[0,\infty)\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x$, for instance.

Comment: So it all depends on the function we are working with?

Comment: Yes, it does.${}$

Comment: If we take the second function you suggested, it is obvious that x goes to infinity, so the function is not bounded from above, so we can't find its supremum, but I would like to ask you whether there  is a way how to prove it.

Comment: To prove what? That my second function has no supremum?

Comment: Yes, please. I'm wondering how could a mathematical proof look like.

Comment: The range of that function is $[0,\infty)$. Since it has no upper bound (there is not real number $M$ such that $(\forall x\in[0,\infty)):x\leqslant M$), it has no supremum.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @abc No. The range of $f$ is $[0,\infty)$ and therefore what I did proves that the range of $f$ has no upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

A supremeum *need* not exist, as witnessed by the continuous function $x\mapsto x$.
A supremum *may* exist as witnessed by the function $x\mapsto 42$.